# MS Access Help to run a query

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I have two tables as follows.[image]

I want to get all members who are active and payment period = fortnightly and corresponding savings record for each member for a specific year and month. Note that some of the members may not have a savings record for given year and month.
I have a query written, but it does not return the members who does not have a savings record in savings table.

```
SELECT Member.memberID As [ID],Member.firstName AS [First Name],
       Member.lastName AS [Last Name], Member.paymentPeriod AS [Payment Period],
       Savings.savingId AS [Savings Id], Savings.enteredAmount AS [Amount]
FROM Member
    LEFT JOIN Savings ON Member.memberID = Savings.memberId
WHERE Member.isActive = 'Active' AND Member.paymentPeriod = 'Fortnightly'
      AND Year(Savings.enteredDate)=2019 AND Month(Savings.enteredDate) = 1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `SAVINGS` conditions from `WHERE` to `ON` to get true `LEFT JOIN` result:

```
SELECT Member.memberID As [ID],Member.firstName AS [First Name],
       Member.lastName AS [Last Name], Member.paymentPeriod AS [Payment Period],
       Savings.savingId AS [Savings Id], Savings.enteredAmount AS [Amount]
FROM Member
    LEFT JOIN Savings ON Member.memberID = Savings.memberId
      AND Year(Savings.enteredDate)=2019 AND Month(Savings.enteredDate) = 1
WHERE Member.isActive = 'Active' AND Member.paymentPeriod = 'Fortnightly';
```

(With those conditions in the `WHERE` clause, you'll get regular `INNER JOIN` result.)

**Edit:** Attempt to avoid "*Join expression not supported error*":

```
SELECT Member.memberID As [ID],Member.firstName AS [First Name],
       Member.lastName AS [Last Name], Member.paymentPeriod AS [Payment Period],
       Savings.savingId AS [Savings Id], Savings.enteredAmount AS [Amount]
FROM Member
    LEFT JOIN Savings ON Member.memberID = Savings.memberId
WHERE Member.isActive = 'Active' AND Member.paymentPeriod = 'Fortnightly'
      AND (Year(Savings.enteredDate)=2019 or Year(Savings.enteredDate) IS NULL)
      AND (Month(Savings.enteredDate) = 1 or Month(Savings.enteredDate) IS NULL);
```

Comment: I tried this but I'm getting the Join expression not supported error :(